# Fill empty fields with previous values in Kusto query in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

**Background**

We have a dataset with the following format in Azure Data Explorer.

| sensorid | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valve1 | 24-03-2021 | 123 |
| valve1 | 23-03-2021 | 234 |
| cylinderspeed | 23-03-2021 | 1.2 |
| valvestatus | 23-03-2021 | open |
| valvestatus | 24-03-2021 | closed |
| cylinderspeed | 25-03-2021 | 2 |

The different sensors have different reporting intervals, some report every second, some a few times per day.

By using this query

```
datatable (sourcetimestamp: datetime, sensorid:string, value:dynamic)
    [datetime(2021-03-23), "valve1", 123,
    datetime(2021-03-24), "valve1", 234,
    datetime(2021-03-23), "cylinderspeed", 1.2,
    datetime(2021-03-23), "valvestatus", "open",
    datetime(2021-03-24), "valvestatus", "closed",
    datetime(2021-03-25), "cylinderspeed", 2]
| summarize average=any(value) by bin(sourcetimestamp, 1s), sensorid
| evaluate pivot(sensorid, any(average))
```

I can generate this table

| timestamp | valve1 | cylinderspeed | valvestatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23-03-2021 | 123 | 1,2 | open |
| 24-03-2021 | 234 |  | closed |
| 25-03-2021 |  | 2 |  |

**The problem**

How can I continue on the above query so I can fill empty cells with the previous value for from that column?

Comment: Ideally, the examples will use the datatable() operator, this will make it much simpler to provide an answer with an example.

Comment: @Avnera excellent idea. I added the source data with datatable()

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the series_fill functions such as [series_fill_forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-forwardfunction). Note that the easiest way to get the arrays to fill is by using the [make-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) operator

since timeseries expects numeric values in the series I translated the enum of the valvestatus to double.

```
datatable (sourcetimestamp: datetime, sensorid:string, value:dynamic)
[datetime(2021-03-23), "valve1", 123, 
datetime(2021-03-24), "valve1", 234, 
datetime(2021-03-23), "valvestatus", "open",
datetime(2021-03-24), "valvestatus", "closed",
datetime(2021-03-23), "cylinderspeed", 1.2,
datetime(2021-03-24), "cylinderspeed", 2]
| extend value = case(value=="open", double(1), value=="closed", double(0), value)
| make-series values = any(value) default=double(null) on sourcetimestamp from(datetime(2021-03-23 00:00:00.0000000)) to(datetime(2021-03-24 00:00:00.0000000)) step 1h by sensorid
| extend values = series_fill_forward(values)
```

Comment: Do you think you could add an example using the base query from the question?

Comment: Added an example. I modified yours a bit. You can do the pivot and the other manipulations before or after the make-series.

Comment: I changed the "productcode" field to "valvestatus". It is there to indicate that some sensor data has string type.

Comment: The time series operators expect a numeric values, You can always translate a string enum into numeric, I modified the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python plugin for that. You first need to enable the plugin in the Azure Portal in the configuration tab of your cluster. I don't know why the Kusto team is taking so long for such a simple operation. I'm waiting for a generic "ffill" since years:

```
.create-or-alter function  ffill(T:(*)) {
T
| evaluate python(
typeof(*),
'result = df.ffill()'
)
}

datatable (num1: int, num2: int)
[
1,0,
int(null), 1,
int(null), 0,
2, int(null),
3, int(null)
]
| invoke ffill()
```